# Mobile website single quote problem

Tags: php, mobile-website

I'm getting the error below on a Nokia N80 when visiting the mobile site I wrote in PHP.... How do I resolve?

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Line Number 22, Column 45:    Click here for T&C's
--------------------------------------------^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably your '&' character which should be escaped to '&amp;' by e.g. [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the & not the '. Probably you need to use htmlspecialchars or htmlentities

Comment: Don't use htmlentities() in XML, only htmlspecialchars(). The only entities in XML are <> and &, which is what htmlspecialchars() encodes. If you use htmlentities all other characters which need to be entity encoded in HTML will be encoded. This will cause unknown entity errors in the XML parser.